# is there a query formula to count the latest value in a specific date for a specific id along with all the unique ids's values?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For example, post id 18158935492035927 has value of 42 in Col `D` in date 08/24 and the same id# has value of 44 in date 08/25.
For date 08/25, is there a query formula to scan all the values in the Col `D` to count the value of 44 and not 42 in 08/25 for this same post id along with all the unique post ids' values?

Like from 08/24 to 08/25 there's total of 3 unique post ids. For date 08/25, is there a formula to **scan all rows in Col `D`** to sum values of (34+0+44) and not (34+42) from col `D`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it would help you if you were to use a cell (like `E2`) where you can store the **latest date in column `A`**

```
=max(A3:A9)
```

Following that, you can **use this formula**

```
=QUERY(A3:D9,"select sum(D) 
              where A=DATE '"&TEXT(E2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
              label sum(D) '' ")
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detail informative solution! Also, will this work if I want to use `max(A3:A)` in your query formula like `=QUERY(A3:D9,"select sum(D) where A=DATE '"&TEXT(max(A3:A), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'label sum(D) '' ")`

Comment: *"Thank you so much for your...."* **1**. Since your original question was answered, please accept it. **2**. Just try it. **3**. Yes it will. **4**. Very good thinking. Do you mind if I update the answer?

Comment: I finally test. It does work. Thank you! @marikamitsos